# GuzzleHttp returns out of memory exception but no issue with postman using the same request

Tags: wordpress, jwt, postman, guzzle

We have a laravel application using GuzzleHttp to interface with a wordpress application. I set up a local copy on my laptop for testing. On my local setup though, the guzzle request returns an out of memory exception

```
Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4292874240 bytes)
```

I started allocating increasingly larger sizes from 1GB to 4GB but still the same error. The code looks like this

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => $headers]);
$req = $client->post('https://local.test/jwt-auth/v1/token', ['body' => $data]);
```

where $data looks something like

```
{
    "username": <user_name>,
    "password": <password>"
}
```

Running this through Guzzle gives me an out of memory exception. However, running the same post request through postman with the same url and login details showed no issues and i was able to get the token. Most of the stackoverflow messages i found said that it's an issue with some other code but i don't think that explains why postman works. jwt-auth is also an established plugin for wordpress as well which we've used for other projects too with no issues.

Has anyone else encountered this before? the php i'm using on my local setup is 7.3.16

Comment: How can you be sure that the exception is returned by Guzzle and not from other part of your code? Have you used try/catch with Guzzle?

Comment: yes. i used try/catch with Guzzle. it stops there then at the caught exception, it shows the out of memory exception

Comment: Can this issue be related to yours: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2555

Comment: @user1165759 i've been doing some testing and i think it doesn't work that well with localhost type urls. If i try a get request like this `$response = $client_test->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com');`, there's no error. But if i try it with one of my localhost urls like this `$response = $client_test->request('GET', 'https://local.test');`, the error occurs.

Comment: @user1165759 i did more testing and it looks like it has an issue with self-signed certificates which i use for my local setup. if i use a local site that does not use a self signed certificate, it's ok. if it does, the error occurs

Comment: @user1165759 i set "verify" -> false to test and it worked. although this is not ideal as in production it works properly

Comment: You can add a config switch: dev/prod that controls the verify attribute

Comment: @user1165759 for certain reasons i was hoping to avoid that and was hoping i could setup some sort of certificate that can be trusted by GuzzleHttp.

Comment: For that you can set your local server's domain to be the same as the production domain accessing it via the hosts file on your local machine and use the production's certificate.